# "No resource found that matches the given name" error

Tags: android, android-xml

In my application I get this error for all drawalbes that I have in the folder res/drawable:

```
[2011-05-15 16:07:47 - Marmara] libpng error: Not a PNG file
[2011-05-15 16:07:47 - Marmara] ERROR: Failure processing PNG image D:\WorkSpace JEE\Marmara\res\drawable\waiting.png
[2011-05-15 16:07:47 - Marmara] D:\WorkSpace JEE\Marmara\res\layout\detail_promo.xml:55: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ombreinterne_imghp').
```

I've tried to move all drawables and add them again, I've tried also to clean the project many times, but none of that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your waiting.png has some problem, Remove that image and check ! Because of some corrupted png file further processing is not happening.

Comment: thanks to you sat , u're right , my file waiting.png est corrupted , because the original one is waiting.gif, and i've changed his extension to a png 
thanks a lot again : for your help , i really appreciate that :)