# Android studio gradle issue

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-studio

i've imported my cordova 3.0 project into Android Studio, when i sync build.gradle file with my project, i have this error code 1:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
```

the error output is about AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
Error:(38, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon').
Error:(39, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(43, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/activity_name').
Error:(47, 43) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/launcher_name').
```

any idea?

Comment: The error says that you have no image named icon in your drawable folder,no string named app_name and so on..

Comment: yes i know, but the fact is that there is this image in this folder

Comment: Then i think a restart of android studio will fix the issue..

Comment: i have the same error after restart android studio :(

Comment: See the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro)

Comment: Do tell me if you have any problems..

Comment: i followed the instructions, but still have the same error, even with build clean command

Comment: see if this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17901362/3168859) helps you..

Comment: nop, it created a new build folder, but with the same issue.

Comment: Do you know where the "res" folder path is specified?

Comment: sorry..didnt get you???what was that??

Comment: i assumed that if the build don't find the files, it because he don't find the "res" folder..? am i right?

Comment: check if you have an entry for the icon in `R.java`

Comment: yes, there is:
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
        public static final int screen=0x7f020001;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int activity_name=0x7f040002;
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040000;
        public static final int launcher_name=0x7f040001;
    }

Comment: is your image inside some other folders???

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21648362/3168859)

Comment: The image is on other folders like bin/res/drawable...
I don't find any menu.xml file in my project, i have a file in res/value/strings.xml and itcontains this: <resources>
    <string name="app_name">MyAppName</string>
    <string name="launcher_name">@string/app_name</string>
    <string name="activity_name">@string/launcher_name</string>
</resources>

Comment: This error taught me how much vital git is.