# Android Studio - No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, android-resources, build.gradle

I am developing an app in Android Studio, I used the Android Asset Studio to make the launcher icon, and then I tried to Copy/Paste the new icon to overwrite the default one (like I always did in Eclipse) and nothing happens, so what I did was changing the name of the default ic_launcher to `a.png` and then from the windows eplorer copy/paste each `ic_launcher.png` in the corresponding mipmap folder, and delete de `a.png`'s files (while Android Studio was running) and then that error was shown.

I tried clean, rebuild, build , refresh, resync the project and nothing happens, I am getting the same error. I also try to rename the build folder to build.old as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893372/error-building-project-in-android-studio-error-no-resource-found-that-matches) thread says, but still the error.

```
Error:(16, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/a.png').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
 ...<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/a.png"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity ...
```

Also I tried to change the value of `android:icon="@mipmap/a.png"` to `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher.png"` but every time I rebuild it changes again to `a.png`.

Would I have to start from 0 and make a new project and copy all the things I have done or there is a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, anything worked and I had to remake the app and copy/paste all clases and activities:

Lesson: Do not mess up  with the project files from the explorer, go for the automatic, frameworked solutions that Android Studio gives to you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me:

I deleted the mipmap folder in android studio and clicked right on res folder -> new -> Image asset, then image selection -> next .....

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify the `.png`

Just do:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/a"
```

Comment: For whatever value I put there, when it rebuilds it goes to a.png

Comment: @El_Mochiq, Try doing a Build Clean